# Use spread operator on NodeList in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I would like to use the ES6 spread operator to convert a NodeList to an Array. My project uses TypeScript and it's throwing an error.

```
const slides = [...document.querySelectorAll('.review-item')];
```

Here is the error that is thrown, **error TS2461: Type 'NodeListOf' is not an array type**

That code is possible in Babel. Is it possible in TypeScript or do I need to use another method like `Object.keys()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) is used with iterables, which `NodeListOf` is. `[...document.querySelectorAll('...')]` is valid in ES6 (as long as DOM iterables are supported by the browser or polyfilled).

The problem is specific to TypeScript which doesn't strictly follow ES specs with ES5 target and lower. Spread syntax is limited to arrays by default, and

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('...')];
```

is transpiled to

```
document.querySelectorAll('...').slice();
```

It will result in error, and type system emits an error on compilation.

One way is to use `Array.from` (can be polyfilled in ES5 environment) to convert an iterable to an array:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('...'));
```

Another way is to [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441292/why-downleveliteration-is-not-on-by-default/55108310#55108310) [`downlevelIteration` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#downlevelIteration). It forces TypeScript 2.3 and higher to treat iterables according to ES specs with ES5 target and lower:

> Provide full support for iterables in for..of, spread and destructuring when targeting ES5 or ES3.

`DOM.Iterable` should be specified in `lib` compiler option to include suitable typings. Since DOM iterators require browser support, they can be polyfilled in older browsers with [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#iterable-dom-collections).

Comment: Are you sure that `querySelectorAll()` is a valid iterable in ALL browsers that support spread syntax?  It wouldn't surprise me if there was a laggard from Redmond.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've double checked, and yes, you are correct on MS, it looks Edge still doesn't have support for DOM iterables, they have to be polyfilled.

Comment: I logged in just to up-vote you. This IMO is the best solution and worked for me. VS Code was serving it as an error prior to this. Thank You!

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, that's true, not sure why I made it so, it was copy and paste, I guess.