# puppeteer page evaluate use require module in page evaluate

Tags: node.js, module, puppeteer, require

i dont understand how to use module in page.evaluate, i also find this post on SO : [How to pass required module object to puppeteer page.evaluate SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815565/how-to-pass-required-module-object-to-puppeteer-page-evaluate)

but i dont understand how to use it, i have had :

```
await page.addScriptTag({ path: './node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js'});
```

i got :

> Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: fs.appendFileSync is not a function

```
const fs = require('fs');

page.evaluate(()=>{
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll("a.myclass.vid");

        elements.forEach((element, index) => {
            fs.appendFileSync("textresult.txt", element.textContent+"\r\n");
        })

    });
```

thanks for your explication :o)

Answer (score 0):

That anonymous function you pass to [page.evaluate()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) runs in the context of the web page puppeteer is running in, so of course it doesn't know what `fs` is. You need to return something from that anonymous function, and then call `fs.appendFileSync` with that:

```
const texts = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return document.querySelectorAll('a.myclass.vid').map((el) => {
    return el.textContent + "\r\n"
  })
})

fs.appendFileSync('textresult.txt', texts)
```

Comment: i also use your idea, but "map" return :

_Error: Evaluation failed: TypeErr
or: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function_

i used this syntax and it works :
`const TitresVideos = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let names = document.querySelectorAll(
   "a.myclass.video"
  );
  let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(names);
  let text_arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
   text_arr.push($vartraited+"\r\n");
  }
  return text_arr;
 })`

Comment: Hi @VeilleurTryToFix , [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a nodeList, not an array. 
In order to use array methods like `.map` or `.forEach`, I usually use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator as follows: `[...document.querySelectorAll( "a.myclass.video" )]`  you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585409/use-spread-operator-on-nodelist-in-typescript)

Comment: Yep sorry, forgot about the return type of `querySelectorAll`, thanks @charlyrl